# Fazer Variável com múltiplos nomes e uma única String de Valor

Tags: javascript, string

Seria possível criar uma única variável que tem a influência mútua por outros nomes nela.

Em outras palavras, nomes diferentes para mesma declaração `var`, e no fim terão o mesmo valor.

## Exemplo

**Estou fazendo assim:**

```
var perfume = "Racco";

var colonia = "Racco";

var roll-on = "Racco";
```

**Desejo algo assim:**

```
var perfume, colonia, roll-on = "Racco"
```

> Não importa! Qualquer um dos três nomes, corresponde a mesma `new String();`.
>
> Basta apenas uma `var`, com diversos nomes, para chamar somente um único **Valor**.

Ha como fazer isso? Depois de declarada mais de uma variável na mesma linha ***trazer um único valor*** para todas elas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode atribuir o mesmo valor a várias variáveis de uma vez da seguinte maneira:

```
var perfume = colonia = rollon = "Racco"
```

Mas no caso acima, se as variáveis `colonia` e `rollon` ainda não tiverem declaradas, elas serão variáveis globais.
Se você deseja criar variáveis para o escopo local e atribuir o mesmo valor à elas você precisa fazer as duas coisas em etapas separadas:

```
var perfume, colonia, rollon;
perfume = colonia = rollon = "Racco";
```

Se na verdade o que você quer é alterar uma só variável e ter o valor "automaticamente" alterado nas outras: No `javascript` isso não é possível com tipos primitivos, somente com tipos complexos, pois eles são passados como referência:

```js
var objeto = {};
objeto.x = 10;
var objeto_2 = objeto;
objeto_2.x = 20;
console.log(objeto.x); // objeto.x == 20
```